# How to replace IN CLAUSE USING EXISTS?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, exists

```
select 
    TV.ATTRIBUTE
FROM
    TABLE_VALUE TV
WHERE 
    TV.NUMBERS IN (SELECT MAX(TV1.NUMBERS) FROM TABLE_VALUE TV1 
                    WHERE TV.UNIQUE_ID=TV1.UNIQUE_ID GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `exists` would help here, because - as you put it - for each `unique_id` there be *many* `numbers` values, and you want to select attribute for highest `numbers` for that particular `unique_id`.

`exists` is useful when you want to check whether something ... well, *exists*, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want `EXISTS`, instead you can use the `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT attribute
FROM   (
  SELECT attribute,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY numbers DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_value
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

or use the `MAX` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT attribute
FROM   (
  SELECT attribute,
         numbers,
         MAX(numbers) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id) AS max_numbers
  FROM   table_value
)
WHERE  numbers = max_numbers;
```

Either option will only read from the table once.

---

If you really did want to use `EXISTS` (or `IN`) then it will be less efficient as you will query the same table twice but you can do it with a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT tv.attribute
FROM   table_value tv
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_value tv1
  WHERE  tv1.unique_id = tv.unique_id
  HAVING MAX(tv1.numbers) = tv.numbers
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lf7_6u7Q)